# Analysis Services Dimension - Key column usage where two attributes are at the same level

Tags: ssas

My query is regarding the setting of the KeyColumn property of a dimension attribute in analysis services (2008). Specifically it boils down to: I have a dimension, there are three attributes which I am currently concerned with: SudoKey, Code and Description.

SudoKey is the most granular, but Code and Description are at the same level, that is to say for every Code member, there is one Description member, and vice versa.

My users want to have access to both individually (some users find codes more efficient, whereas others prefer to work with the descriptions).

I am currently thinking that for efficiency rather than define SudoKey > Code *and* SudoKey > Description relationships, I should be defining a SudoKey > Code relationship and using Code as the KeyColumn value for Description (with Description for the NameColumn value)... Only I am not confident about what I am doing and success is critical!

Any input would be much appreciated! :)

Edit: What I mean to say is, I don't know if this will work/if it will have the intended effect of reducing the work which Analysis Services has to do.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

your dimension key will be the unique attribute, the one its directly referenced on the fact tables, so if on the fact you have sudoKey, use it.

About browsing, if you configure the dimension relationship correctly your users will be able to browse the cube by any if the attributes.

You configure the dimension relationship (and this is very important, probably one of the most important configurations you have on the cube) on the second tab of the dimension configuration. In this case you would have your key attribute as the main and the other two directly related to it

Comment: Thanks for the response! However my question is about the key values for the attributes. The sudokey is already the key value for the dimension, but each attribute has its own attribute key and I'm wondering if using one attribute as the key for another, where they are both the same granularity, will help improve efficiency...

Comment: I'm sorry but this answer has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 0):

What your are explaining is a typical dimension and the both of the relationships should be to the key column. It would not be more work for SSAS. All attributes in the dimension are potentially viewable and usable by end-users so I don't see why are you are trying to change the relationships to the key.